# GooglePlacesAutocomplete Basic Search

Tags: react-native, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to limit GooglePlacesAutocomplete to only conduct a basic search? My hunch is it is either within the `query` or I need to remove the `fetchDetails={true}` and only return the data...I want to do this so I do not get charged a fee for searching.

```
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        debounce={200}
        listViewDisplayed="auto"
        minLength={2}
        placeholder="Search..."
        autoFocus={false}
        returnKeyType={'search'}
        fetchDetails={true}
        query={{
            key: API_KEY,
            language: 'en', 
            types: '(cities)' 
        }}
        styles={{
            textInputContainer: {
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                borderTopWidth: 0,
                borderBottomWidth:0,
            },
            textInput: {
                marginLeft: 0,
                marginRight: 0,
                height: 38,
                color: '#5d5d5d',
                fontSize: 16
            },
            predefinedPlacesDescription: {
                color: 'black'
            },
        }}
        renderDescription={value => value.description}
        onPress={(data, details) => { 
            updateLocationArray(data, details, timeFrame);
        }}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research i found out that you can only do a search with google places api. There is no free version of search with google maps. Hope that helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps Platform Places API uses a pay-as-you-go pricing model and every requests are billed accordingly. You can see more details [here](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing).

The Google Maps Platform offers $200 USD free tier credit to each billing account which you can use to have a free requests to the APIs. Just be cautious to not exceed this limit as you will be billed accordingly once this free credit was exhausted. You can also follow this [optimization guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/optimization-guide#places) to help you optimize your usage.

There are also variety of searches that you can make with the Places API. You can have *Find Place* , *Nearby Search*, *Text Search* requests. Learn more about it on the Google Maps Platform's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search).

Hope this helps!